# Flashback Table in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How to use the Flashback Table feature in Oracle 10g. I want to know all the steps involved in detail.

Answer (score 1):

This article will give you a good start: [Flashback Table](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/10gdba/week5_10gdba.html)

e.g. if you accidentally dop a table, simply use this command:

```
FLASHBACK TABLE mytable TO BEFORE DROP;
```

if you want to revert the contents of a table to an earlier time:

```
FLASHBACK TABLE mytable TO SCN 2202666520;
```

or

```
FLASHBACK TABLE mytable TO TIMESTAMP 
 TO_TIMESTAMP(29-JUN-2009 10:30', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI');
```

Documentation: [Flashback Technology: Recovering from Logical Corruptions](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10734/rcmflash.htm)

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey!!!
So is it that we do not have to do any settings in init.ora file in case of FlashBack Table as in the case of FlashBack Database???

Comment: Flashback table uses the same method as flashback database - it uses the undo blocks to retrieve the prior state of the data. i.e. if your undo retention period isn't long enough it will not be able to help you. You'll want to check your UNDO_MANAGEMENT and UNDO_RETENTION parameters.